# "Invalid object name" error in adapter.Fill method

Tags: sql, ado.net, dataset

I'm trying to make a DataSet from all tables of the AdventureWorks2012 database. But I'm getting an "Invalid object name " error in the adapter.Fill method.

Any ideas?

```
private void openDBButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter;
        SqlCommand myCommand;

        string conStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + dbPath.Text +
            ";Integrated Security=true";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        connection.Open();

        DataTable tables = connection.GetSchema("Tables");

        foreach (DataRow table in tables.Rows)
        {
            if (table["TABLE_TYPE"].ToString() != "BASE TABLE")
                continue;
            string tableName = table["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            string sqlCmd = "SELECT * FROM " + "[" + tableName + "]";
            //SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, connection));
            //adapt.FillSchema(myDataSet, SchemaType.Mapped, tableName);

            myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, connection);
            myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, tableName); // here i'm get in trouble :)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of tableName when the exception is thrown?

Comment: thats 'ScrapReason', The first 'BASE TABLE' in iteration.